# Perform actions on page change or close

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, spawn

I have a NodeJS/Express (4.10.2) function which calls an external subprocess through spawn:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var java = spawn("java", ['-cp', 'lib\\*;bin', 'com.my.app.App']);
    ...
}
```

What I'd like to do is add some kind of anonymous function which will get called when the page is changed, tab is closed, or even refreshed. In short, I'd like to kill the spawned process!

Google isn't being good to me in researching this.

Comment: Why do you want the process running during a page view, and only during a page view? Sounds like a potential [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me

Comment: There may also be a way to keep the request open, ie ['long polling'](https://github.com/pascalopitz/long_polling_example/blob/master/test.js) and receive an event when the connection is closed. your problem is really knowing when to call java.kill() and how to keep a reference around

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is send a cookie with a unique value with every request, and store that value in a map as the key, with the value being the child process object so you can kill it.

Then add an `unload` handler on the page in Javascript to fire a request to a new URL with that unique value to allow you to do the killing.

e.g. your express code becomes something like:

```
var javaSessions = {
    _counter: -1
};
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var javaSessionId = javaSessions._counter++;
    res.cookie('java_session_id', javaSessionId);
    var java = spawn("java", ['-cp', 'lib\\*;bin', 'com.my.app.App']);
    javaSessions[javaSessionId] = java;
    ...
});
app.get('/unload/:id', function (req, res) {
    var java = javaSessions[req.params.id];
    javaSessions[req.params.id] = null;
    java.kill();
});
```

Then in `index.html`, add the following markup down the bottom (assuming you don't need to target browsers older than about Internet Explorer 8):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onunload = function () {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        javaSessionId = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)java_session_id\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1"); // regex from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example_.232.3A_Get_a_sample_cookie_named_test2
    req.open("GET", "/unload/" + javaSessionId);
};
</script>
```

You might also be able to get the cookie value from the request, instead of needing to explicitly read it in Javascript and send it as a URL parameter. It may already be sent with the request.

You will need to test all of this, this is all very hypothetical code you will have to try yourself.

Comment: Nice I'll try this -- though I was hoping NodeJS had some built in functionality that could detect when the end user moved from the page (since it ought to detect when it doesn't need to "server" the page anymore midstream?)

Comment: If you are just responding to a request, once the response has been sent, normally express doesn't keep anything around. That is what is meant when they say that HTTP is "stateless". Every request is treated as if it is the very first one it has ever received. If you want to maintain state on the server, you need to do that all manually.

Comment: The only possible way a server might be able to know if a client cancelled a request is if the client aborts while the server is still sending data. But when all you're doing is sending some HTML, with some headers (that include a cookie in this case), once that is received by the client the server forgets everything about that client and that request.